# Ruby: Raising custom namespaced exception ends with an error

Tags: ruby, class, exception, namespaces

Following code:

```
module MyServerAPI
  class BaseException < Exception
  end

  class Base
    protected
    def self.msa_get(url)
      #................
      raise BaseException "HTTP request error: #{ex.message}\n"
      #................
    end
  end

  class Function < Base
    def self.list
      #................
      res = msa_get('functions')
      #................
      res
    end
  end
end

result = MyServerAPI::Function.list
```

executes with an error:

```
undefined method `BaseException' for MyServerAPI::Function:Class
```

How to raise my custom namespaced exception from within the same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a comma:

```
raise BaseException, "HTTP request error: #{ex.message}\n"
```

without a comma, the code translates to:

```
raise(BaseException("HTTP request error: #{ex.message}\n"))
```

so the interpreter searches for a method called `BaseException`...

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it should be

```
 raise BaseException.new("HTTP request error: #{ex.message}\n")
```